# Error with referencing to an array in ViewController from View

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

i have an NSMutable array function in ExercisesViewController.m and want to call that array into ExercisesView.m.

ExerciseViewController.m

```
- (NSMutableArray*)qBlock{

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someaddress.php"];
NSError *error;
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url 
                                                usedEncoding:&encoding 
                                                       error:&error];
const char *convert = [response UTF8String];
NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:convert];
NSMutableArray *sample = [responseString JSONValue];


return sample;}
```

ExercisesView.m:

```
 - (id) initWithParentViewController:(ExercisesViewController *)parent {
if ((self = [super init])) {
    // Update this to initialize the view with your own frame size
    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    refParentViewController = parent;
    NSMutableArray *qnBlock = [refParentViewController:qBlock];}
```

But there seems to be some error in linking the reference. I just have a gut feeling its syntax issue. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

It's just a syntax error. Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *qnBlock = [refParentViewController qBlock];
```

Comment: i did but the error returned:Instance method '-qBlock' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Comment: Check that you also have a declaration of your method in your `ExerciseViewController.h` file.